# Count all outgoing http/s requests

Tags: monitoring, https

I would like to know how many http/s requests i make in a month with my computer (Ubuntu 18.10)

Does ubuntu have any command to see that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: No.

You would have to run a packet tracer, such as tcpdump or wireshark, and count them from that.

OR:

Make some iptables rule that makes a log entry for each connection (which might not be be the same number as requests, if multiple can be done per connection.

However, because HTTPS is encrypted, there isn't a good way to isolate "HTTPS: GET" from the rest of the traffic, as can be done for unencrypted HTTP. For example, I was able to extract this from my tcpdump logs for one computer and HTTP only on my network:

```
doug@DOUG-64:~/tcpdump/104$ gunzip -c all0.txt.gz | grep "IP 192\.168\.111\.101\." | grep "\.80:" | grep "HTTP: GET" | grep "^2019-01-" | wc -l
29835
doug@DOUG-64:~/tcpdump/104$ gunzip -c all0.txt.gz | grep "IP 192\.168\.111\.101\." | grep "\.80:" | grep "HTTP: GET" | grep "^2019-02-" | wc -l
69684
```

Meaning it did 29835 HTTP requests in January and 69684 in February.